# Generate pages from markdown files in github automatically

Tags: plugins, multisite, github, markdown

I have a lot of markdown documents stored in GitHub.  The .md documents change often so it is difficult to track changes. What I am currently doing is create a template and read content from the URL and insert into my template to get in the proper format.

What I want to do now is - Github MD files should be converted as a page in my Wordpress site automatically. It should get updated when GitHub is updated. it would be better if admin have control over the content.

Does anyone have any idea about how should I proceed?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Github has an API that should allow you to pull data from your Github `.md` files, and (probably) update them from WordPress. [Here's their documentation.](https://developer.github.com/v3/)